# 302 status on my heroku django app

Tags: python, django, heroku, http-status-code-302

I have deployed my django app to heroku. when i try to access the app from my computer it is working fine -- all the get and post ajax request. all are working fine. But when I am trying to acces the map from other computer it gives below error:

```
2017-07-05T11:49:32.879209+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/times
heet/?from=getTimeSheet&selectedWeek=Fri+Jul+07+2017" host=myotes.herokuapp.com
request_id=8d4749b2-b1d8-4681-9134-c155dc41165f fwd="115.118.212.176" dyno=web.1
 connect=0ms service=63ms status=302 bytes=302 protocol=https
```

I have decorators in my views:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def priortime(request):
```

It is status 302 which is related to redirect. But why I am getting this from machine and not from other. Is it related to chrome version or anything else?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're getting redirected on one machine and not from the other, it suggests that you are logged in on one machine but not the other. Chrome version shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i logged out from both machines and then log in.again one works fine and other gives 302

Comment: That suggests that there is something wrong with your login. There's no reason for the code you have posted to behave differently on different machines.

Comment: yes, the problem is with login logic. I removed the login_required decorator and it worked fine. Thanks for the suggestions.But why login_required worked fine on one machine and not on the other?

Comment: `login_required` should work exactly the same on both machines. I believe it's your *login* that is behaving differently. You haven't shown any code that would explain different behaviour.